API limit reached to update the data from Catalyst Datastore table
I have reached the API limit in the development environment, for updating the data from the Catalyst Datastore table using the Node SDK method.
This is the response that I'm getting while updating the Catalyst Datastore table row.

Request failed with status 400 and code : FREE_USAGE_LIMIT_REACHED , message : You have exhausted the free tier allowance for Datastore - Update.


Ok, sounds quite clear. What is your question?

You might have faced the "FREE_USAGE_LIMIT_REACHED" issue, if you have exhausted the free tier API limit for updating the Catalyst Datastore table row. Hence, you are facing the issue.
To resolve this issue, kindly set up a payment method to continue using this resource. kindly choose any pricing plan by clicking the upgrade button in the top right corner of the catalyst Console and provide the card details. Then, you will not face any API reached limit issue in the Development environment.
As of now, Catalyst follows two pricing models a Pay-as-you-go model and a Subscription model. You can choose the model based on your application usage. You can find their help documentation here for the same.
